# AWS AppSync onUpdate Subscription not working on simulator

Tags: android, subscription, aws-appsync

I am trying to run the subscription on Android. I am able to make all other queries run like create, update, list, etc on the android client but not subscription. However, on AWS Appsync console I can open two console tabs and create a subscription and add new objects, it's working there, I get callbacks.

None of the methods are triggered on client when I add objects from console(Android simulator).

> I am using client key for auth mode.

Below is my code:

```
 private void subscribeNew(){
        OnCreateRtGuestSubscription subscription = OnCreateRtGuestSubscription.builder().build();
        subscriptionWatcher = mAWSAppSyncClient.subscribe(subscription);
        subscriptionWatcher.execute(new AppSyncSubscriptionCall.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@Nonnull Response response) {
                Log.i("Response", response.data().toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@Nonnull ApolloException e) {
                Log.i("Response", e.toString());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.i("Response","");

            }
        });
    }
 private AppSyncSubscriptionCall.Callback<OnUpdateRtGuestSubscription> subscriptionCallBack= new AppSyncSubscriptionCall.Callback<OnUpdateRtGuestSubscription>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@Nonnull Response<OnUpdateRtGuestSubscription> response) {
                            Log.i("Response", "");

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@Nonnull ApolloException e) {
                            Log.i("Response", "");

        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
                            Log.i("Response", "");

        }
    };



    private void subscribeEdit(){
        OnUpdateRtGuestSubscription subscription = OnUpdateRtGuestSubscription.builder().build();
        AppSyncSubscriptionCall subscriptionWatcher=this.mAWSAppSyncClient.subscribe(subscription);
        subscriptionWatcher.execute(subscriptionCallBack);
    }
```

> 2019-05-27 14:45:55.540 1362-1384/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying
>   enough data to HAL, expected position 13086062 , only wrote 13086000
>   2019-05-27 14:45:55.548 12881-13064/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: Adding
>   listener [com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest.MainActivity$2@361b720] to
>   SubscriptionObject:
>   com.amazonaws.amplify.generated.graphql.OnCreateRtGuestSubscription@b3f4623
>   got:
>   com.amazonaws.amplify.generated.graphql.OnCreateRtGuestSubscription@b3f4623
>   2019-05-27 14:45:55.548 12881-13064/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/SubscriptionObject: Adding listener to
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.appsync.subscription.SubscriptionObject@926e8d9
>   2019-05-27 14:45:55.551 12881-13063/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: Adding
>   listener [com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest.MainActivity$1@3f740ef] to
>   SubscriptionObject:
>   com.amazonaws.amplify.generated.graphql.OnUpdateRtGuestSubscription@836217f
>   got:
>   com.amazonaws.amplify.generated.graphql.OnUpdateRtGuestSubscription@836217f
>   2019-05-27 14:45:55.551 12881-13063/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/SubscriptionObject: Adding listener to
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.appsync.subscription.SubscriptionObject@47b254c
>   2019-05-27 14:45:55.564 12881-13067/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   D/RetryInterceptor: Retry Interceptor called 2019-05-27 14:45:55.564
>   12881-13067/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   D/AppSyncSigV4SignerInterceptor: Signer Interceptor called 2019-05-27
>   14:45:55.566 12881-13067/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   D/AppSyncSigV4SignerInterceptor: Subscriber ID is
>   61c60911-18ea-4ac2-8a7f-79f13d7b03e6 2019-05-27 14:45:55.773
>   12881-13067/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest I/RetryInterceptor:
>   Returning network response: success 2019-05-27 14:45:55.775
>   12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: subscribe
>   called for
>   com.amazonaws.amplify.generated.graphql.OnCreateRtGuestSubscription@b3f4623
>   2019-05-27 14:45:55.776 12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   D/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: Adding
>   subscription object
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.appsync.subscription.SubscriptionObject@926e8d9
>   to topic
>   443301200413/eytajgboqjcllkyv6jkqycc4me/onCreateRTGuest/08388b10f697efc944dc0f96750be6b366bb7d1e9b6305769ea132320fa7470d.
>   Total subscription objects: 2 2019-05-27 14:45:55.776
>   12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: Attempting to
>   make [1] MQTT clients] 2019-05-27 14:45:56.779
>   12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/MqttSubscriptionClient: Subscription Infrastructure: Set
>   subscription message transmitting to false for client
>   [tgvihzfuync35pl4m6ihy6gidu] 2019-05-27 14:45:56.779
>   12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/MqttSubscriptionClient: Subscription Infrastructure: Set Connection
>   transmitting to false for client [tgvihzfuync35pl4m6ihy6gidu]
>   2019-05-27 14:45:56.780 12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/MqttSubscriptionClient: Subscription Infrastructure: Set
>   subscription message transmitting to false for client
>   [tgvihzfuync35pl4m6ihy6gidu] 2019-05-27 14:45:56.780
>   12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/MqttSubscriptionClient: Subscription Infrastructure: Set Connection
>   transmitting to false for client [tgvihzfuync35pl4m6ihy6gidu]
>   2019-05-27 14:45:56.780 12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: Connecting
>   with Client ID[tgvihzfuync35pl4m6ihy6gidu] 2019-05-27 14:45:56.780
>   12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/MqttSubscriptionClient: Subscription Infrastructure: Calling MQTT
>   Connect with actual endpoint for client ID[tgvihzfuync35pl4m6ihy6gidu]
>   2019-05-27 14:45:57.143 12881-13072/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   D/AlarmPingSender: Register alarmreceiver to
>   MqttServiceMqttService.pingSender.tgvihzfuync35pl4m6ihy6gidu
>   2019-05-27 14:45:57.145 12881-13072/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   D/AlarmPingSender: Schedule next alarm at 1558961187145 2019-05-27
>   14:45:57.146 12881-13072/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   D/AlarmPingSender: Alarm scheule using setExactAndAllowWhileIdle,
>   next: 30000 2019-05-27 14:45:57.151
>   12881-12881/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: Connection
>   successful for clientID [tgvihzfuync35pl4m6ihy6gidu]. Will subscribe
>   up to 2 topics 2019-05-27 14:45:57.151
>   12881-12881/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: Subscribing to
>   MQTT
>   topic:[443301200413/eytajgboqjcllkyv6jkqycc4me/onUpdateRTGuest/08388b10f697efc944dc0f96750be6b366bb7d1e9b6305769ea132320fa7470d]
>   2019-05-27 14:45:57.151 12881-12881/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/MqttSubscriptionClient:
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.appsync.subscription.mqtt.MqttSubscriptionClient@5c66981Subscription
>   Infrastructure: Attempting to subscribe to topic
>   443301200413/eytajgboqjcllkyv6jkqycc4me/onUpdateRTGuest/08388b10f697efc944dc0f96750be6b366bb7d1e9b6305769ea132320fa7470d
>   on clientID [tgvihzfuync35pl4m6ihy6gidu] 2019-05-27 14:45:57.152
>   12881-12881/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: Subscribing to
>   MQTT
>   topic:[443301200413/eytajgboqjcllkyv6jkqycc4me/onCreateRTGuest/08388b10f697efc944dc0f96750be6b366bb7d1e9b6305769ea132320fa7470d]
>   2019-05-27 14:45:57.152 12881-12881/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/MqttSubscriptionClient:
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.appsync.subscription.mqtt.MqttSubscriptionClient@5c66981Subscription
>   Infrastructure: Attempting to subscribe to topic
>   443301200413/eytajgboqjcllkyv6jkqycc4me/onCreateRTGuest/08388b10f697efc944dc0f96750be6b366bb7d1e9b6305769ea132320fa7470d
>   on clientID [tgvihzfuync35pl4m6ihy6gidu] 2019-05-27 14:45:57.152
>   12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: Made [1] MQTT
>   clients 2019-05-27 14:45:57.152
>   12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: Unmuting the
>   new clients [1] in total 2019-05-27 14:45:57.152
>   12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/MqttSubscriptionClient: Subscription Infrastructure: Set
>   subscription message transmitting to true for client
>   [tgvihzfuync35pl4m6ihy6gidu] 2019-05-27 14:45:57.152
>   12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/MqttSubscriptionClient: Subscription Infrastructure: Set Connection
>   transmitting to true for client [tgvihzfuync35pl4m6ihy6gidu]
>   2019-05-27 14:45:57.152 12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: Muting the old
>   clients [ 1] in total 2019-05-27 14:45:57.152
>   12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/MqttSubscriptionClient: Subscription Infrastructure: Set
>   subscription message transmitting to false for client
>   [7aybllsw45gfnbuahn3khahrr4] 2019-05-27 14:45:57.153
>   12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/MqttSubscriptionClient: Subscription Infrastructure: Set Connection
>   transmitting to false for client [7aybllsw45gfnbuahn3khahrr4]
>   2019-05-27 14:45:57.153 12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: Closing the
>   old clients [1] in total 2019-05-27 14:45:57.153
>   12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/RealSubscriptionManager: Subscription Infrastructure: Closing
>   client:
>   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.appsync.subscription.mqtt.MqttSubscriptionClient@90ffefa
>   2019-05-27 14:45:57.153 12881-13065/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   V/MqttSubscriptionClient: Closing MQTT client
>   [7aybllsw45gfnbuahn3khahrr4 2019-05-27 14:45:57.163
>   12881-13067/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest D/RetryInterceptor:
>   Retry Interceptor called 2019-05-27 14:45:57.163
>   12881-13067/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   D/AppSyncSigV4SignerInterceptor: Signer Interceptor called 2019-05-27
>   14:45:57.163 12881-13067/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest
>   D/AppSyncSigV4SignerInterceptor: Subscriber ID is
>   61c60911-18ea-4ac2-8a7f-79f13d7b03e6 2019-05-27 14:45:57.199
>   12881-13040/com.example.umarfarooque.rtdbtest D/AlarmPingSender:
>   Unregister alarmreceiver to MqttService7aybllsw45gfnbuahn3khahrr4

Comment: Can you post a code snippet of how you are constructing the `AWSAppSyncClient` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ok so for those who face similar issues in future, the problem lies in
>   the schema used to define subscription.

By default, AWS adds the parameters which you need to put else it doest work and you dont get any callbacks. So, I modified my schema for subscription to somethning like this and pulled the new changes to my app:

```
type Subscription {
    onCreateGuest: Guest
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["createGuest"])
    onUpdateGuest: Guest
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["updateGuest"])
    onDeleteGuest: Guest
        @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["deleteGuest"])
}
```

This [link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=875559) helped me understand and find the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try to put the watcher as a class level variable and not declare inside your method.

Comment: Nope doesnt work still.. I am adding and editing objects from the console but nothing is detected in the app.. i added logs for reference